# Compiler explorer and GCC have different outputs

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, g++

I have some C code that when given to Compiler Explorer, it outputs:

```
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-4], al
        mov     eax, ecx
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-8], al
        mov     eax, edx
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-12], al
```

However if I use GCC or G++ then it gives me this:

```
        mov     BYTE PTR 16[rbp], al
        mov     eax, edx
        mov     BYTE PTR 24[rbp], al
        mov     eax, ecx
        mov     BYTE PTR 32[rbp], al
```

I have no idea why the BYTE PTRs are different. They have a completely wrong address and I don't get why they are before the [rdp] part.

If you know how to reproduce the first output using gcc or g++ please help!

Comment: What is your version of gcc? Note the offsets may still be correct depending on how rbp was set up earlier. Also there is the red zone available.

Comment: gcc.exe (GCC) 8.2.0

Comment: Well that's windows. Code will be different, in particular because windows does **not** have the red zone.

Comment: I am trying to use it to write a qemu kernel so...

Comment: Then it's up to you to decide what which ABI you want to follow. Also you probably want to enable optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> gcc.exe (GCC) 8.2.0

Looks like GCC for the Windows x64 calling convention is using the shadow space (32 bytes above the return address) reserved by its caller.  Godbolt's GCC installs target GNU/Linux, i.e. the x86-64 System V ABI.

You can get the same code on Godbolt by marking your function with `__attribute__((ms_abi))`.  Of course that means your caller has to see that attribute in the prototype so it knows to reserve that space, and which registers to pass function args in.

The Windows x64 calling convention is mostly worse than x86-64 System V; fewer arg-passing registers for example.  One of its only advantages is easier implementation of variadic functions (because of the shadow space), and having some call-preserved XMM regs.  (Probably too many, but x86-64 SysV has zero.)  So more likely you want to use a cross compiler (targeting GNU/Linux) on Windows, or use `__attribute__((sysv_abi))` on all your functions.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html)

The XMM part of the calling convention is normally irrelevant for kernel code; most kernels avoid saving/restoring the SIMD/FPU state on kernel entry/exit by not letting the compiler use SIMD/FP instructions.